# Build failure while running shell command from Jenkins

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins

I am invoking shell script to build my source code via jenkins 'Invoke Shell' option. My command goes like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/repo
cd /home/administrator/administrator/repo_sync
whoami
source ./build/envsetup.sh 
choosecombo release project_int_factory eng
```

Resulting to which i am getting below error. I have given full permission to folder. Source code location is /home/administrator/administrator/repo_sync. I have tried with **sudo chmod +x administrator** & **sudo chmod 777 administrator** but nothing helps. plus whoami return **jenkins**

```
Building in workspace /home/administrator/administrator/repo_sync
    [repo_sync] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1461193343405073934.sh
    + export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/var/lib/jenkins/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/administrator/pawan/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools:/home/administrator/pawan/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools:/usr/bin/repo
    + cd /home/administrator/administrator/repo_sync
    + whoami
    jenkins
    + source ./build/envsetup.sh
    /tmp/hudson1461193343405073934.sh: 5: /tmp/hudson1461193343405073934.sh: source: Permission denied
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jenkins scripts (and "Execute Shell" build step **is** a script) are executed with the user that Jenkins runs with. By default, Jenkins runs as `jenkins` user

Your script is executed as "jenkins" user, as is evident from:
`+ whoami`
`jenkins`

You should be executing your `chmod` commands for `jenkins` user, not `administrator`.

Answer (score 31):

Add the execution bit to your .sh file

```
git add --chmod=+x "filename"
```

Answer (score 19):

Running `bash command.sh` worked for me.

Comment: I thought it was a direct answer.  The way the author is running shell scripts does not work due to permissions.  Running the shell scripts as I have outlined will let the author run the she shell script without a permission error.